# Pandas.rolling_apply lambda on multiple columns of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I want to do a `pandas.rolling_apply` involving multiple columns of a `DataFrame`.

I can do it with one column of a `DataFrame` "df" like this:

```
a = pd.Series(np.random.randn(12))
pd.rolling_apply(df['Col1'], 12, lambda x: x@a.values, min_periods=12)
```

But I really want to incorporate two of the dataframe's columns into the `rolling_apply`.  Is something like the following possible?

```
pd.rolling_apply(df, 12, lambda x: x['Col1']@a.values+x['Col2']@a.values, min_periods=12)
```

(Python complains if I try to bring a column reference inside the lambda this way.)

Comment: did you try adding `axis=1` in the apply call? `axis` defaults to 0 which means the `apply` is by rows, `axis=1` is by columns.

Comment: @wkzhu no that doesn't work: I do need the rolling to be by rows.  It's just that I want to reference two different columns at each point in the `apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `pandas.rolling_apply` is deprecated.

In this case, since you can decompose the desired lambda into separate calls, you could do the following:

```
window = df.rolling(12, min_periods=12)
window['Col1'].apply(lambda x: x@a.values) + window['Col2'].apply(lambda x: x@a.values)
```